# Infinite Scroll on Mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scroll on my website and it works well on browsers on any computer, but it has issues on mobile browsers.  So far, on chrome, if I don't zoom in or out it works ok but once I zoom either way it stops working.  On safari it doesn't work at all.  This is the code that I am using:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    console.log(" window.scrollTop = " + $(window).scrollTop() + " document.height=" + $(document).height() + " window.height =" + $(window).height());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        load();
    }
});
```

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Try `touchmove` instead of `scroll`.

Comment: Will touchmove work on laptop browsers as well? How would I keep the functionality the same on normal browsers and make it work on mobile browsers as well?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

> $(window).height()

try using

> window.innerHeight