# $(document).height() != $(window).height() in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-website, infinite-scroll

This question has been asked before ([Infinite Scroll on Mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619264/infinite-scroll-on-mobile-browsers)) but with no response.

I'm trying to implement infinite scroll.

The function to check whether the document is at the bottom, causing more to load is:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
```

This works fine on my computer, but does not work on any browsers on mobile (iOS).

On iPhone 5s for my page, `$(document).height()` reports 1055 and `$(window).height()` is 504.
But even at the bottom of the page, `$(window).scrollTop()` is at most 507.
Therefore `507 != 551 (1055-504)`

I believe this may have something to do with `$(window).height()` reporting the height of the viewport which is somehow different in mobile.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does your viewport meta tag look like?

Comment: Try instead (document.documentElement.clientHeight) and see it it helps with mobiles. --- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight

Comment: jQM provides  $.mobile.getScreenHeight(), does that work any better?

Comment: @Josh I don't have a viewport meta tag

Comment: @Tasos ezanker I'll try these, but I would like this to work on PC and mobile

Comment: If you are using Jquery-Mobile there is a good solution here --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728140/jquery-mobile-1-4-infinite-scrolling-window-scroll-not-firing

Comment: @Tasos That was indeed the answer! And it works on both PC and mobile! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The magic statement for me, worked for mobile as well as desktop Chrome browsers:

```
$(document).height() - window.visualViewport.height
```